# Redis connection refused with nodejs/docker and docker networks

Tags: node.js, docker, redis

I've been trying to run my nodejs container and get it to connect to my Redis docker container with no avail. Even placing them in the same network does not work, I keep receiving `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379`.

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    networks:
      - redis-net
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: ./
    container_name: nodejs
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - redis-net

  nginx:
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./nginx-conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
    networks:
      - redis-net

networks:
  redis-net:
    driver: bridge
```

nodejs server code:

```
const host = 'redis-net'
const port = 6379
const redisClient = redis.createClient({port:port, host:host})
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I do not know if it is typo, but hosts should point to `redis` instead of `redis-net`. As the first one is the service name, and the second one is the network name.

Comment: Hey that was a good catch, I thought that would fix it but it surprisingly hasnt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not calling `createClient` correctly and it is defaulting to, well, defaults. The host and port need to be specified inside of a socket property. Like this:

```js
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
  socket: {
    port: port,
    host: host
  }
})
```

Details on the various options for `createClient` can be found in the [Client Configuration Guide](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/client-configuration.md) that is linked off the README for [Node Redis](https://github.com/redis/node-redis).

Also, after creating the client you will need to connect. Be sure to handle any errors before you do so. Like this:

```js
redisClient.on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err))
await redisClient.connect()
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This was the answer! The tutorial I was following didn't include the `socket` argument. Thanks friend